# Loading addthis via async plugin

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, addthis

I would like to get this file in the dom without using a dumb `script` tag. However It's timing out.

```
require(["async!http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js"], function(addthis){

});
```

Here's the console error:

```
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: async!http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js_unnormalized2,async!http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
```

Comment: So I tried hitting the two urls that async was trying to grab and addthis_widget.js is fine, but addthis_widget.js_unnormalized2 cannot be found. Do you know why async is looking for this?

Comment: I have no clue what's going on there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with requirejs (just starting to look into it tonight!), but you could do it this way:

```
var jsAddThis = document.createElement('script'),
    head      = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

jsAddThis.async = true;
jsAddThis.type  = 'text/javascript';
jsAddThis.src   = 'http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js';

head.appendChild(jsAddThis);
```